# MySQL 8.0.35 doesn't select addresses when coordinates whithin polygon

Tags: mysql, mysql-spatial

I created a minimum SQL code to reproduce an issue that I have

```
CREATE SCHEMA `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
use test;
create table addresses (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    addr VARCHAR(255),
    lng decimal(11,8),
    lat decimal(10,8),
    address_point POINT SRID 4326 NOT NULL,
    SPATIAL KEY sp_index (address_point)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

insert into addresses(addr, lng, lat, address_point) 
values('test', 15.0791673, 37.5071435, ST_SRID(POINT(15.0791673, 37.5071435), 4326));

SET @point_to_check = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(15.0791673 37.5071435)', 4326);
SELECT * FROM addresses;

SET @polygons = ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((8.8 36.0, 17.8 36.0, 17.8 47.1, 8.8 47.1, 8.8 36.0)),((12.4 41.9, 12.6 41.9, 12.6 42.1, 12.4 42.1, 12.4 41.9)))', 4326);
SELECT ST_Within(@point_to_check, @polygons) AS is_within_poligons; -- returns 1

-- empty result
select id, address_point from addresses 
where ST_WITHIN(address_point, @polygons);

SELECT address_point, @point_to_check,
    ST_Within(address_point, @polygons) AS table_point,
    ST_Within(@point_to_check, @polygons) AS var_point,
    ST_Equals(address_point, @point_to_check) AS compare
FROM addresses;
```

Why last 2 SELECTS return an empty result while `SELECT ST_Within(@point_to_check, @polygons) AS is_within_poligons;` returns 1?

UPD 1. I checked ST_AsText()(syggested bellow) and got this: `POINT(37.5071435 15.0791673), POINT(15.0791673 37.5071435)`. Looks like `ST_SRID(POINT(15.0791673, 37.5071435), 4326)` switch coordinates, because `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(15.0791673 37.5071435)', 4326)` works correct

Comment: probably the problem is due to the precision and format of the POINT data stored in the address_point column compared to the POINT created as @point_to_check.

Comment: you could check by peeking into the textual representation using `
SELECT ST_AsText(address_point), ST_AsText(@point_to_check),
    ST_Within(address_point, @polygons) AS table_point,
    ST_Within(@point_to_check, @polygons) AS var_point,
    ST_Equals(address_point, @point_to_check) AS compare
FROM addresses;
`

Comment: @weshouman you are right. POINT(37.5071435 15.0791673), POINT(15.0791673 37.5071435). But why did it move from latitude to longitude, I specify SRID for all. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I'm not really sure

Comment: @weshouman I have updated my question with details. ST_GeomFromText('POINT(15.0791673 37.5071435)', 4326) works well, but I don't wanna play with strings

Comment: @weshouman ST_SRID(POINT(lon, lat), 4326) is flipping coordinates, but ST_GeomFromText keeps order. It is weird, I tried SRID 3857 and it keeps the same order. Now I am a bit confused about what should I use and whether should I flip coordinates in MULTIPOLYGON if I will use 4326.

Comment: may be trying 3857 and using ST_Transform would work around that?

Comment: No, I figured it out. When I use ST_SRID(POINT()) I have manually flip long and lat. So it would be ST_SRID(POINT(lat, long), 4326) and then it works correctly. You may check this query
`SELECT ST_Longitude(ST_SRID(POINT(45, 90), 4326)), ST_Longitude(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(45 90)', 4326));`. I didn't find anything about it in documentation, just one bug similar to it and one question on SO